# Send route to Garmin Gpsmap using nmea0183

Tags: serial-port, nmea, garmin

I'm trying to send a route in NMEA0183 from a COM port on my computer to a Garmin GPSMAP421.

The waypoints do go in to the chartplotter by the WPL-sentence, but the RTE-sentence doesn't seem to work with Garmin.

It seems that Garmin has their own approach by some thing called "Garmin protocol".

Does anyone know how to set up the specs to communicate with this protocol? Should it really be 9600 baud rate instead of the normal 4800? Has anyone some example sentences to send?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here goes: I use the 'gpsbabel' program for this. See https://www.gpsbabel.org/. If the route is in gpx file myroute.gpx, and the navigator is at /dev/ttyUSB0, the command would be

```
gpsbabel -r -i gpx -f myroute.gpx -o garmin -F /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I don't think recent Garmin chartplotters/mfds support the "Garmin protocol", but I believe this would work with a GPSMAP 421.